# При подключенной библиотеке string программа не работает на других компьютерах

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, dll, c++-cli

Начал учить Windows Forms на ++ (не на шарпе). Столкнулся с такой проблемкой: я создал небольшое приложение, используя разные библиотеки, string, к примеру. Но потом прога не работает на других компах, хотя на моем отлично, когда я убираю библиотеку стринг (код с использованием стрингов тоже), программа отлично работает на других компах!

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы программа работала на других компах?

Comment: А что означает «не работает»?

Comment: @petruska, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.